# How can I extract columns name from row value of another table(oracle sql)?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have 2 tables:

**table1**

| no | a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
| x2 | 10 | 11 | 12 |
| x3 | 20 | 21 | 22 |

**table2**

| from_val | in_out | cf_pv | term |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | out | cf | b |
| b | out | pv | b |
| c | in | cf | e |

Define `sum_out` is sum of `a`, `b`, `c` in **table1** with condition `in_out='out'` in **table2** and `sum_cf` is sum of `a`, `b`, `c` in **table1** with condition `cf_pv='cf'` in **table2**.

Shortly, values of `from_val` in **table2** are columns name i.e. `a`, `b`, `c` in **table1**.

How can I extract and calculate `sum_out` or `sum_cf` of every `no` in Oracle?

```
sum_out of x1 = 2 + 3
sum_out of x2 = 10 + 11
sum_out of x3 = 20 + 21

sum_cf of x1 = 2 + 4
sum_cf of x2 = 10 + 12
sum_cf of x3 = 20 + 22
```

Thanks!

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

in additional,

i want to calculate

```
sum_out and cf of x1= 2 (=a)
sum_out and cf of x2= 10 (=b)
sum_out and cf of x3= 20 (=c)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Sample data

```sql
WITH
    tbl_1 AS
        (
            Select 'x1' "COL_NO",  2 "A",  3 "B",  4 "C" From Dual Union All
            Select 'x2' "COL_NO", 10 "A", 11 "B", 12 "C" From Dual Union All
            Select 'x3' "COL_NO", 20 "A", 21 "B", 22 "C" From Dual 
        ),
    tbl_2 AS
        (
            Select 'A' "FROM_VAL",  'out' "IN_OUT",  'cf' "CF_PV",  'begin' "TERM" From Dual Union All
            Select 'B' "FROM_VAL",  'out' "IN_OUT",  'pv' "CF_PV",  'begin' "TERM" From Dual Union All
            Select 'C' "FROM_VAL",  'in'  "IN_OUT",  'cf' "CF_PV",  'end' "TERM" From Dual          
        ),
```

2. Create CTE (formulas) that generates formulas for IN_OUT = 'out' and For CF_PV = 'cf'

```sql
  formulas AS
    (
        Select
            CASE WHEN IN_OUT = 'out' THEN IN_OUT END "IN_OUT", 
            LISTAGG(FROM_VAL, ' + ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY FROM_VAL) OVER(PARTITION BY IN_OUT) "IN_OUT_FORMULA", 
            CASE WHEN CF_PV = 'cf' THEN CF_PV END "CF_PV",  
            LISTAGG(FROM_VAL, ' + ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY FROM_VAL) OVER(PARTITION BY CF_PV) "CF_PV_FORMULA"
        From
            tbl_2
    ),
```

| IN_OUT | IN_OUT_FORMULA | CF_PV | CF_PV_FORMULA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | C | cf | A + C |
| out | A + B | cf | A + C |
| out | A + B |  | B |

3. Another CTE (grid) to connect COL_NO to formulas

```sql
  grid AS
    (
        Select   
            t1.COL_NO,
            CASE WHEN f1.IN_OUT = 'out' THEN f1.IN_OUT END "IN_OUT", CASE WHEN f1.IN_OUT = 'out' THEN f1.IN_OUT_FORMULA END "IN_OUT_FORMULA", 
            CASE WHEN f1.CF_PV = 'cf' THEN f1.CF_PV END "CF_PV", CASE WHEN f1.CF_PV = 'cf' THEN f1.CF_PV_FORMULA END "CF_PV_FORMULA"
        From
            tbl_1 t1
        Left Join
            formulas f1 ON(f1.IN_OUT Is Not Null AND f1.CF_PV Is Not Null)
   )
```

| COL_NO | IN_OUT | IN_OUT_FORMULA | CF_PV | CF_PV_FORMULA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | out | A + B | cf | A + C |
| x2 | out | A + B | cf | A + C |
| x3 | out | A + B | cf | A + C |

4. Main SQL to get the final result

```sql
    SELECT
        g.COL_NO,
        g.IN_OUT,
        g.IN_OUT_FORMULA,
        CASE WHEN g.IN_OUT = 'out' And INSTR(IN_OUT_FORMULA, 'A') > 0 THEN A ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN g.IN_OUT = 'out' And INSTR(IN_OUT_FORMULA, 'B') > 0 THEN B ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN g.IN_OUT = 'out' And INSTR(IN_OUT_FORMULA, 'C') > 0 THEN C ELSE 0 END "CALC_OUT",
        --
        g.CF_PV,
        g.CF_PV_FORMULA,
        CASE WHEN g.CF_PV = 'cf' And INSTR(CF_PV_FORMULA, 'A') > 0 THEN A ELSE 0 END + 
        CASE WHEN g.CF_PV = 'cf' And INSTR(CF_PV_FORMULA, 'B') > 0 THEN B ELSE 0 END +  
        CASE WHEN g.CF_PV = 'cf' And INSTR(CF_PV_FORMULA, 'C') > 0 THEN C ELSE 0 END "CALC_CF"
    FROM
        grid g
    INNER JOIN
        tbl_1 t1 ON(g.COL_NO = t1.COL_NO)
```

R e s u l t :

| COL_NO | IN_OUT | IN_OUT_FORMULA | CALC_OUT | CF_PV | CF_PV_FORMULA | CALC_CF |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | out | A + B | 5 | cf | A + C | 6 |
| x2 | out | A + B | 21 | cf | A + C | 22 |
| x3 | out | A + B | 41 | cf | A + C | 42 |